# How do I change the visibility of elements in livewire?

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I want to make this login form.
But my livewire doesn't work when I pushed this button.

What should I do?
I read reference, however I can't find about visible/invisible.
It is possible that I have made some mistake in building the environment.

LoginForm.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class LoginForm extends Component
{
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $showPassword = false;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.login-form');
    }

    private function resetInputFields(){
        $this->name = '';
        $this->email = '';
        $this->password = '';
    }

    public function toggleShowPassword()
    {
        $this->showPassword = !$this->showPassword;
        $this->emitSelf('refresh');
        logger('Password visibility toggled: '.$this->showPassword);
    }

    public function login()
    {

    }
}
```

login-form.blade.php:

```html
@extends('components.layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="login">
                <h3 class="text-center mb-4">login</h3>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="email">email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" wire:model="email" placeholder="email" autocomplete="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <label for="password">password</label>
                    @if ($showPassword)
                        <input type="text" id="password" class="form-control" wire:model="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="current-password">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" wire:click="toggleShowPassword">invisible</button>
                    @else
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" wire:model="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="current-password">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" wire:click="toggleShowPassword">visible</button>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: WSL2 Ubuntu22.04 php8.3 Laravel10 Livewire3.X

Comment: Do you have any other livewire components in your project that work? Do you have `@livewireScripts` in the header tag of your guest layout?

Comment: Yes. It is in @extends('components.layouts.app')

Comment: @soundflix You are discriminating against non-English speaking people.

Comment: @vr_min_chan: What gives you this impression?

Comment: @soundflix あなたがしたことはこういうことです。非英語圏の人間にネイティブレベルの英語や文化を求める行為がレイシストと違うと思いますか？あなたにはこの質問の意味が理解できていたはずです。なのに、わざわざ揚げ足を取る行為が侮辱的だとわかりませんか？私はスタックオーバーフローでこのような仕打ちを受けたのは初めてです。それとも私が読み手にとって失礼にあたるような英語の文章を書きましたか？英語をマスターしているあなたは英語を使えない人間を見下していますよね？

Comment: @vr_min_chan You feel discriminated because I corrected "dosen't" to "doesn't" while reviewing? I would have done that if you were Shakepeare in person. And I'm not english-native btw.